# What does Walt Whitman mean by "going in for my chances"?

Tags: meaning, poetry, walt-whitman

From "Song of Myself" by Walt Whitman:

> What is commonest, cheapest, nearest, easiest, is Me,
>   Me going in for my chances, spending for vast returns,
>   Adorning myself to bestow myself on the first that will take me,
>   Not asking the sky to come down to my good will,
>   Scattering it freely forever.

What does it mean to *go in for* something in this contest?

I just feel that it means "I bet on my chances, so I expect the vast returns for this spending". Am I right?